# Voltar para inicio da condição quando for solicitado

Tags: c

Não posso usar função, queria saber como voltar para uma determinada linha do código quando o número 0 for pressionado, exemplo:

```
system(color 7);
printf("Teste");
printf("Teste01");
printf("Pressione 0 para reiniciar");
scanf("%d", &jog);
```

Agora como faço para se ele digitar 0, a execução voltar para a linha do `system()`? Com função seria fácil, mas não posso usar então como vou fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de não ser a melhor opção, uma opção é o `goto`.

```
voltaAqui:
... código
goto voltaAqui;
```

Comment: Por que não seria a melhor opção? `goto` é controle de fluxo :P

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Eu acredito que criar funções é melhor :)

Comment: Também acho que criar função deixa o código mais limpo etc.. Mas é isso aí que eu queria, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Pode colocar o código dentro de um loop e verificar se o valor da variável `jog` é diferente de 0. Se for, você interrompe o loop:

```
int jog;

while(1){

  // código...

  printf("Pressione 0 para reiniciar");
  scanf("%d", &jog);

  if(jog) break;
}
```

Comment: Geralmente eu uso esse, sem o break. Mas ia deixar o código maior, o goto veio bem a mim

Answer (score 2):

```
for (;;) {
    /* codigo */
}
```

ou

```
while (1) {
    /* codigo */
}
```

ou

```
do {
    /* codigo */
} while (1):
```